# Rails routing more complex :constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently if you wish to add a constraint there are many ways to do it but as I see currently you can only include one definitive method which is called. E.g.

```
Class Subdomain

  # Possible other `def`s here, but it's self.matches? that gets called.

  def self.matches?( request )
    # Typical subdomain check here
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != "www"
  end

end
```

The problem with the above approach is it doesn't handle routes prefixed in www, that is admin and www.admin are indistuingishable. More logic can be added, but if this was required over a set of static subdomains like admin, support, and api you currently need to make SubdomainAdmin, SubdomainSupport etc....

This can be solved with regex as follows in `routes.rb`:

admin

```
:constraints => { :subdomain => /(www.)?admin/ }
```

api

```
:constraints => { :subdomain => /(www.)?api/ }
```

If requests were even more complex than this things get tricky. So is there a way to add individual methods inside a class used for constraints?

Essentially, how is the below achieved? Is it even possible? Whats the best method of white-listing subdomains to use?

E.g.

```
Class Subdomain

  def self.admin_constraint( request )
    # Some logic specifically for admin, possible calls to a shared method above.
    # We could check splits `request.subdomain.split(".")[ 1 ].blank?` to see if things are prefixed with "www" etc....
  end

  def self.api_constraint( request )
    # Some logic specifically for api, possibly calls to a shared method above.
    # We could check splits `request.subdomain.split(".")[ 1 ].blank?` to see if things are prefixed with "www" etc....
  end

  def self.matches?( request )
    # Catch for normal requests.
  end

end
```

With which we can now call constraints specifically as follows:

```
:constraints => Subdomain.admin_constraints
```

And all generic constraints as follows:

```
:constraints => Subdomain
```

Is this possible in Rails 4.0.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The router will call the `#matches?(request)` method on whatever object you pass the route. In the case of

```rb
:constraints => Subdomain
```

you're giving the route the `Subdomain` Class object. However, you could also pass an instance, which you could configure via arguments. e.g.,

```rb
Class Subdomain
  def initialize(pattern)
    @pattern = pattern
  end

  def matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present? && @pattern ~= request.subdomain
  end
end

# routes.rb

namespace :admin, constraints: Subdomain.new(/(www.)?admin/) do
  # your admin routes here.
end
```

NOTE: I didn't verify that code works, I just wrote it off the top of my head, so consider it more of pseudo-code than implementation ready.

Also, you can see an example of this technique, with some more details, at: [Use custom Routing Constraints to limit access to Rails Routes via Warden](https://www.codementor.io/tips/8132473431/use-custom-routing-constraints-to-limit-access-to-rails-routes-via-warden).